Searching on 20 AMI IDs with a page-size of 10 takes over 13 minutes
I have a bash script, using aws cli, that is meant to search for AMI IDs (currently, there are only 20), sort them and output in json.
When I set the --page-size to 1000, the query returns in 9 seconds.
When I set the --page-size to 100, the query returns in 79 seconds.
When I set the --page-size to 10, the query returns in 797 seconds.
Each query returns the same expected result set.
Can you point out any errors with my code which would cause such abysmal run times?
#!/bin/bash

# Define the filters
filters=(
    "Name=tag:REDACTED,Values=REDACTED"
    "Name=tag:REDACTED,Values=REDACTED"
    "Name=tag:REDACTED,Values=REDACTED"
)

# Initialize an empty array to store all AMI details
all_amis=()

# Initialize the starting token
next_token=""

# Loop to handle pagination
while : ; do
    start_time=$(date +%s)
    if [ -z "$next_token" ]; then
        echo "---NO TOKEN"
        response=$(aws ec2 describe-images --filters "${filters[@]}" --query 'Images[*].{ImageId: ImageId, CreationDate: CreationDate} | sort_by(@, &CreationDate)' --output json --page-size 10)
    else
        echo "---TOKEN FOUND"
        response=$(aws ec2 describe-images --filters "${filters[@]}" --query 'Images[*].{ImageId: ImageId, CreationDate: CreationDate} | sort_by(@, &CreationDate)' --output json --page-size 10 --starting-token "$next_token")
    fi
    end_time=$(date +%s)
    echo "API call duration: $((end_time - start_time)) seconds"

    # Extract AMI details and next token
    amis=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.[] | [.ImageId, .CreationDate] | @tsv')
    echo "AMIS: $amis"

    # Check for the presence of NextToken and extract it if present
    if [[ "$response" == *"NextToken"* ]]; then
        next_token=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.NextToken')
    else
        next_token=""
    fi
    echo "NEXT_TOKEN: $next_token"

    # Append the AMI details to the array
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r image_id name creation_date; do
        all_amis+=("$image_id $name $creation_date")
    done <<< "$amis"

    # Break the loop if there is no next token
    if [ "$next_token" == "" ]; then
        break
    fi
done

# Print all AMI details
echo "Total AMIs: ${#all_amis[@]}"
for ami in "${all_amis[@]}"; do
    echo "$ami"
done


my guess would be the time it takes to make the aws ec2 calls; if you reduce the page size by a factor of 100 (1000 down to 10) I'd expect the overall time to go up by a factor of 100 (9 secs up to 900 secs), and while 797 != 900 it is within what I'd call the margin of error (88x as opposed to 100x); speeding up bash in this case will come in the form of reducing the number of times through the main loop, which it appears is accomplished with the larger page size of 1000; is there a reason to cut the page size down to 100 or 10?

Yes, just leave page size at 1000 (or explain why not) (-; Also consider [mcve] ing your question. Isn't the problem just in 1 or 2 lines of code? Good luck.

If there are only 20 records to search on, then the page size of 1000 and 100 should take the same time, shouldn't they?  And a page size of 10 should only take 2x the time of 1000, as it would require (2) aws cli calls.  Am I not understanding something?  Also, wanted to reduce the page size to 10 so I could prove multiple calls work with a next_token.

from a bash perspective you're incurring a moderate overhead for the 7 (?) subshells you're invoking on each pass through the main loop; the more times through the loop the higher this subshell overhead; replace var=$(date ...) with printf -v var '%(s)T' to eliminate 2 subshell calls per loop; perhaps replace var=$(echo "$string" | jq ...) with var=$(jq ... <<< "$string") to reduce subshell overhead from 2 to 1; reducing the number of times through the loop (and thus total number of subshells) will still be the biggest time saver

The aws command, from the terminal, also takes ~80 seconds to successfully return: aws ec2 describe-images --filters "${filters[@]}" --query 'Images[*].{ImageId: ImageId, CreationDate: CreationDate} | sort_by(@, &CreationDate)' --output json --page-size 100

how many passes through the main bash / while loop are being performed for each page size setting? does the aws / --page-size 10 command, run from the command line, take ~800 secs?

I'm only seeing (1) pass through the while loop.  And after adding --debug to the query, I'm seeing a lot of chatter, yet no ERRORS or WARNINGS.

Can I ask... Why are you wanting to list the AMIs? Are you wanting a list of your own AMIs, or 'all AMIs' that are available for you to use? If you add --owners self then it will only return your AMIs, which should make things faster.

I recently created a new AWS account for my team to use for a specific project.  We should be the only users of this account.  Maybe my assumption is incorrect, but I'm assuming a "describe-images" command will only be looking at the 20 AMIs in this specific account.
